# SQL Query: If Exists, Update, Else Insert, followed by addition of IDs to linking table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a single SQL query that does something like the following pseudocode. The intention is to parse a URL, and add its constituent words to a word table. If they already exist, increment their counter. Finally, add the URL's ID and each of the constituent word IDs to a table which links them as foreign keys.

```
if (existsInTable(form, lemma, category))
    occurenceCount++;
else 
    insertInTable(form, lemma, category);
insertInLinkTable(urlID, getIDinTable(form, lemma, category));
```

I hope that makes sense. Note that I already have the value for the URL's ID saved as a PHP variable from earlier, but I need to get the ID for the word I've just inserted to add it to the linking table.

I have a query I wrote to show what I mean, but there's no way it's a functional query and probably doesn't even make sense syntactically. How could I go about this?

```
IF EXISTS 
(
    SELECT * FROM Words_Table 
    WHERE 
        word LIKE '{$input[0]}' and 
        lemma LIKE '{$input[1]}' and 
        category LIKE '{$input[2]}' 
        LIMIT 1
)
    UPDATE Words_Table 
    SET occurrenceCount  = occurrenceCount + 1 
    WHERE 
        word LIKE '{$input[0]}' and 
        lemma LIKE '{$input[1]}' and 
        category LIKE '{$input[2]}'
ELSE
    INSERT INTO Words_Table 
    (word, lemma, category, occurrenceCount) 
    VALUES('{$input[0]}',   '{$input[1]}', '{$input[2]}', 1)
INSERT INTO Linking_Table (url_id, word_id) 
    VALUES
    (
        $URLid, 
        (
            SELECT id FROM Word_Table
            WHERE 
                word LIKE '{$input[0]}' and 
                lemma LIKE '{$input[1]}' and 
                category LIKE '{$input[2]}' 
                LIMIT 1
        )
    )
```

I'm pretty sure I can't use a SELECT query in place of a value like I do at the end there, and I'm sure there's a way to go about this without repeating the same WHERE query three times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should accomplish what you need:

[INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)